# Google Cloud VM creates new version on deploy

Tags: python, google-app-engine, deployment, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I am running a Virtual Machine on Google Cloud and am using their SDK to deploy with the following command:

```
gcloud preview app deploy ./app.yaml
```

The deployment works, however for every deployment a new instance is created which can only be reached by adding the version id to the domain name. I tried removing older instances through the developer dashboard but they just restart directly after that.

How can I remove the newly created instances and overwrite the default version on the main domain by default when deploying?

Comment: you can set newly created version as a default (or any other version), at developer console

Comment: But how exactly? I've been deleting instances from Compute Engine > VM Instances but they just reappear. Also I can't set any default there...

Comment: Ah I think I found it. Under App Engine > Versions. That's confusing, but it seems to work. Thank!

Comment: Instance it's an instance of Module/Version, each module have a default version that will be started for processing a request

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this directly from `gcloud`, use the following two flags:

- `--set-default`:

  > Set the deployed version to be the default serving version.
- `--version`:

  > The version of the app that will be created or replaced by this
  >   deployment. If you do not specify a version, one will be generated for
  >   you.

(both from `gcloud preview app deploy --help`).

If you set `--version` to be the same each time, the current version deployed at that URL will be overwritten, and a new version will not be created on each deployment.

If you use `--set-default`, the deployed version can be accessed just using the domain name (without the version as a subdomain).

Deleting the other versions by hand in the developer console will be the simplest way to get rid of them.

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what was missing in my answer: a way to automatically do this on deployment.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out you can't edit this under Computer Engine > VM Instances. You have to look under AppEngine > Versions and change the default version there + delete the older ones.